Jewel (diamond?) heist movie from 1970s with real diamond switched for a fake of same weight
I remember watching a film in the early 1970s which was a comedy jewel heist.
It was colour with English language and started in a holiday location, blue skies, coastline etc.
I seemed to remember the plot being the creation of a synthetic diamond that had to be an exact replica of the large stone to be stolen and getting the weight the same was crucial.
The jewel to be stolen was in a protected display case with a weight sensitive alarm so the alarm had to be immobilised whilst the fake and real jewels were switched, after that there were a series of switches with a 2nd thief and the twist was that there were 2 fakes in circulation.
Maybe I've muddled 2 movies together in my head. It isn't The Hot Rock, Jack of Diamonds or Topkapi as I've already ruled them out! 

I hope we figure this out.  I think I've seen (part of) this before, but after a LOT of trolling through IMDB I can't come up with better (wrong) guesses than the OP...

Thanks I've now found the movie I was looking for, it was Mr Jerico but it must've been preceeded by a trailer for Return of the Pink Panther or the initial scenes from Return of the Pink Panther. Remembering the zip-wires and removal of the diamond from the display case and then the Mr Jerico movie about swapping paste for real diamonds obviously made me think it was all one film and my (false) memory probably added bits in to make sense of it. I've been tring to fathom this out for decades to watch those scenes again so might have tried this site years ago. thanks for helping

Ok, could it be Gambit, with Michael Caine and Shirley MacLaine?  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambit_(1966_film)
trailer: 


They're stealing a statuette, not a gem, but it involves the main character stealing a statuette, then watching as it is revealed that the real statuette is in a hidden compartment, then purportedly switches them (but apparently doesn't?  so that both fakes can be sold?)

Thanks for suggesting, I watched it just in case and really enjoyed it. Have now found the movie(s) I was looking for. Muddled 2 together in my head so  no wonder it was an impossible ask
